# Why do I get many newlines after bash while loop?

Tags: bash

I have a simple bash script that reads a csv file, loops over all columns, find the uniq values and prints them on screen. However, after the while loop a lot of newlines are printed. I cannot find why...

```sh
#!/bin/bash

INPUTFILE="loop_through_a_comma_separated_file__test_file.csv"

# Set a FIELD variable at 1 to test when to stop looping
FIELD=1

# Find how many columns are in csv and tick by 1
COUNT=`sed 's/[^,]//g' $INPUTFILE | wc -c`; let "COUNT+=1"

# Keep looping until the field is less than the count+1 (until all fields are caught in the loop)
while [ "$FIELD" -lt "$COUNT" ]; do

        # Read the file and pull the current field number and print it to terminal
        cat $INPUTFILE | cut -d, -f$FIELD | sort -n | uniq

        # Increment the FIELD variable
        ((FIELD++))
done
```

This is the content of file loop_through_a_comma_separated_file__test_file.csv:

```
Name,Address,Phone,Cell,Email,Nickname
1,2,3,4,5,6
7,8,9,10,11,12
1,2,3,4,5,6
```

Comment: Your `COUNT=` line appears to count the number of values (i.e. rows * columns) instead of number of columns. That does not appear to be what you want?

Comment: `Remark:` `don't know how to remove them` if you put your file content with 4 leading spaces or inside three backticks \`\`\`<text>\`\`\` as you did with script code, you can preserve all the lines vebatim. `let "COUNT+=1"` - `let` is an old utility. Use `((...))` as you did with `((FIELD++))` - `((COUND+=1))` or for portability `COUNT=$((COUNT + 1))`

Comment: consider updating the question with the desired output (for the given sample data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you `echo` the `COUNT` then you can see that the value is `25`(i.e. `number of rows * number of columns + 1` ).

```
COUNT=`sed 's/[^,]//g' $INPUTFILE | wc -c`; let "COUNT+=1"
```

The above line counts all the words seperated by `,` which is `24`. Sed processes the file line by line. So, in first line it counts 6 words, then it goes to next line etc till the end. ie. total 4 lines. Since each line has 6 words, you get a total of 24 as the output of the `sed`.

So, 25 lines will be printed in total (i.e it stops when value of `FIELD` becomes `25` ). From line 6 (i.e. when `FIELD` is `6`) onwards in the output, blank space will be printed.

Shortly, as in the comment pointed out by **Matt Shin** value of `COUNT` is wrong. If you change the value of `COUNT`, you will get the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `sed` for this.

```
IFS=, read -a fields < "$INPUTFILE"
COUNT=${#fields[@]}
```